# Problems with Which statement doesn't evaluate

Tags: programming, conditional

```
 One1 = {-1, 1, 2}
 Two1 = {1, 2, 3}
 One2 = {3, 2, 1}
 Two2 = {-4, -3, 2}

 rrr1[t_] := {One1} + t {Two1}
 rrr2[s_] := {One2} + s {Two2}
 Print[rrr1[t] == rrr2[s]]
 Which[One1/Two1 == One2/Two2, Print["Parallel"], rrr1[t] == rrr1[s],
   ParametricPlot3D[{rrr1[t], rrr2[s]}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, -2, 2}],
     Solve[rrr1[t] == rrr2[s], {t, s}], rrr1[1],
  True, Print["Skew"]]
```

The parametric plot line requires a comma, a semi colon gives a red highlight.

EDIT:

```
One1 = {-1, 1, 2}
Two1 = {1, 2, 3}
One2 = {3, 2, 1}
Two2 = {-4, -3, 2}



      rrr1[t_] := {One1} + t {Two1}
rrr2[s_] := {One2} + s {Two2}
Values = Solve[rrr1[t] == rrr2[s], {t, s}]
FirstValue = Values[[All, 1, 2]]
SecondValue = Values[[All, 2, 2]]
Which[One1/Two1 == One2/Two2, Print["Parallel"], 
 FirstValue == SecondValue,
 ParametricPlot3D[{rrr1[t], rrr2[s]}, {t, -2, 2}, {s, -2, 2}],
 Solve[rrr1[t] == rrr2[s], {t, s}], rrr1[1],
  True, Print["Skew"]]
```

Now I get Symbol::argx: Symbol called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
and
Set::wrsym: Symbol Values is Protected.

Comment: Yes, because `rrr1[t] == rrr1[s]` doesn't evaluate to `True` or `False`. You haven't provided values for `s` and `t`. If you want to check for structural equality then use `===`

Comment: Please check my edit.

Comment: `Values` is a built-in function. Don't use variables starting with a capital to avoid accidentally trying to overwrite system symbols (which is what causes the `Set::wrsym` message).